# How to let Python find the HTML tidy lib

Tags: windows, dll, tidy

I downloaded the libtidy.dll and libtidy.lib and put them in the corresponding folders of python27. Then I installed pytidylib for python.
But when I type

```
import tidylib
```

I got below error which indicates python can't find the module

```
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
   import tidylib
   File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\tidylib\__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
   raise OSError("Could not libtidy using any of these names: %s" % (",".join(LIB_NAMES)))
   OSError: Could not libtidy using any of these names: libtidy,libtidy.so,libtidy-  0.99.so.0,cygtidy-0-99-0,tidylib,libtidy.dylib,tidy
```

Anyone can help one this?

Answer (score 1):

Pytidylib requires tidy, which is not a python package. You have to install it yourself and make it accessable.

If using windows, just extract the tidy package somewhere and add its bin folder to windows' PATH.

Answer (score 0):

> I downloaded the libtidy.dll and libtidy.lib and put them in the corresponding folders of python27

Don't do that. Use `pip` or `easy_install` to manage your packages.

**Update** Apparently your question is about how to install dlls on windows. Put them in any directory on the windows PATH.

Comment: I either can download the source codes or built dll. I used `easy_install` to install the pytidylib.

Comment: @user3658215 Then follow the installation instructions for libtidy.

Comment: After some research I found python just can't load the dll. Possibly it is because the dll file is not right.

Comment: @user3658215 Python can't load the dll because it's not a python module. You need to put the dll on the windows path, and use a module which interfaces with it.